# Why would you ever want a Java file with no public classes declared in it?

Tags: java, class

There is a statement in the book I'm reading for the SCJP qualification, it says :

> Files with no public classes have no
>   naming restrictions

That has made me ask, **why would you ever want to do this?**

If there are no public classes, then how could other classes ever import and use the file? The only purpose I can see is if the file runs standalone in itself, which could also be odd, such as have an entire application in one file

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is valid for [package-private](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) classes as well. And you can use package-private classes within the same package. (And in that case you don't have to import it, because it's in the same package.)

For example, the `JapaneseImperialCalendar` class is package-private, because it is only used from `Calendar.createCalendar(..)` - it is not part of the public API. You can't directly instantiate the japanese calendar, but you can still use it *by its interface*. Same goes for all unmodifiable collections that are obtained by methods like `Collections.unmodifiableList(..)` - they are package-private.

So the `.java` file of `JapaneseImperialCalendar` could've been arbitrary. However, it is advisable not to diverge from the established practice of naming even package-private files after the class name.

Comment: As reinforcement of keeping the established naming practice just in case, note too that [the JLS states](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#26783) that "the host system may...enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file [with that naming convention]" even in the case where the type is only "referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared" (package-private).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a file named `package-info.java`, which contains only a `package` statement. The javadoc 1.5+ tool treats a javadoc comment on this package statement exactly like a `package.html` file. In addition, you can add package-level annotations such as `@Generated` to this statement, which you can't do in `package.html`.

Because `package-info` is not a valid Java identifier, there is no risk of this file ever clashing with an existing Java class (i.e. backwards compatibility).

Comment: Actually, it's a very fitting example for why such a file would have no naming restrictions. The file name isn't even a legal class name, so it couldn't possibly be a file with a class in it (but it's still a *.java that the compiler is going to process according to the rules laid out in the JLS).

Answer (score 1):

From [Java Classes](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~hasti/cs368/JavaTutorial/NOTES/Java-Classes.html), you have public classes and package classes. Package classes are considered "private" so that you can only use them within the package itself. This is the default, i.e. no *public* is specified.

Public classes are, of course, classes that you can create anywhere.

Answer (score -1):

Even though I am very late in answering the question, but this will surely help a lot. If I am not wrong, your concrete question boils down to this -  What is the significance of a class declared with no **no explicit modifier**?

Have a look at this class present in **java.util** package-

```
class JumboEnumSet<E extends Enum<E>> extends EnumSet<E>
```

Also see within the same package-

```
class RegularEnumSet<E extends Enum<E>> extends EnumSet<E>
```

You see both of them are declared with **no explicit modifier**. Have you wondered why the **package private** restriction? Here's the reason from the amazing book **Effective Java 2nd Edition by Joshua Bloch #Item1**

> The class **java.util.EnumSet (Item 32)**, introduced in release
>   1.5, has
>   no public constructors, only static factories. They return one of two implementations, depending on the size of the underlying enum type: if it has sixty-four or fewer elements, as
>   most enum types do, the static factories return a RegularEnumSet
>   instance, which is backed by a
>   single long; if the enum type has sixty-five or more elements, the factories return a JumboEnumSet instance, backed by a long
>   array.

Move swiftly on, he further adds-

> The existence of these two implementation classes is invisible to
>   clients. If RegularEnumSet ceased to offer performance advantages for
>   small enum types, it could be eliminated from a future release with no
>   ill effects. Similarly, a future release could add a third or fourth
>   implementation of EnumSet if it proved beneficial for performance.
>   Clients neither know nor care about the class of the object they get
>   back from the factory; they care only that it is some subclass of
>   EnumSet.

Answer (score -2):

I don't agree with the non-restriction. Each java file should contain only one top level class, and the file name should be the same as the class name, public or not. I don't think javac would like this very much (or any human being)

```
A.java
    class B

B.java
    class A
```

---

http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.3

> 7.2 Host Support for Packages
>
> Each host determines how packages,
> compilation units, and subpackages are
> created and stored, and which
> compilation units are observable
> (§7.3) in a particular compilation.
>
> 7.2.1 Storing Packages in a File System
>
> As an extremely simple example,

---

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

> both source and class files must have
> root names that identify the class.
> For example, a class called MyClass
> would be written in a source file
> called MyClass.java and compiled into
> a bytecode class file called
> MyClass.class.

Comment: It is allowed, like it or not. It's a different question whether this makes sense in the general case

Comment: @bozho what was the original source of the file name convention? it's been a long while.

Comment: JLS perhaps. I don't know how did it get there :)

Comment: @bozho JSL wouldn't dictate such things.